# Need assistance in writing a apex trigger to add a list of standard lines to an object

Tags: apex, trigger

Newbie to salesforce and looking for a way to write a trigger that will create 11 line items for when a field is update.  Object is credit request and when this is saved would like multiple credit lines to be added which is also an object.  Below is a rough start, but looking for guidance.  Picture attached showing what I would like to see after the request is saved and line items automatically created.

```
trigger TestCreditLinesAdd on Credit_Request__c(after insert){
List < Credit_Lines__c > creditlines = new List < Credit_Lines__c > ();
for (Credit_Request__c cr: trigger.new) {
    creditlines.add(new Credit_Lines__c(.Quantity__c = 0.001));
}
insert creditlines;}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want the trigger to run when a field is updated you will need to include `after update` either in place of or in addition to `after insert`.

Comment: Yes will need to enable updates based on master qty.  But if a line item is deleted intentionally need to ensure only the line items remain are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of hints, showing how to check for a field value change and how to hook the child objects up to the parent object via the parent object Id:

```
for (Credit_Request__c cr: Trigger.new) {
    if (cr.FieldName__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(cr.Id).FieldName__c) {
        creditlines.add(new Credit_Lines__c(
                Credit_Request__c = cr.Id,
                Quantity__c = 0.001
                ));
        creditlines.add(new Credit_Lines__c(
                Credit_Request__c = cr.Id,
                Quantity__c = 0.002
                ));
        // Add others for a total of 11 child objects
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is updating with some minor changes.  I would like to add and update a Product__c field to each line item.  This caused a failure.  I put the terminology in '', but still fails.  Would this be because this Product__c field looks up the product object

Comment: @ChrisSecrist I presume the `Product__c` field is a lookup? You will need to get hold of the right `Id`s somehow - via a query? - and set them in each item.

Comment: Thanks yes it is a look up., will look into leveraging the id.